# ngTransclude directive doesn't work, can't realize where I'm wrong

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

Trying to use [ngTransclude](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) first time to make custom directive, to achieve the floating label functionality as shown here: [Floating label pattern — Angular JS](http://codepen.io/anatoly314/pen/LNvMYK), but it doesn't work.

Here is my directive code:

```
.directive('floatingLabel', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                label: '@',
                value: '='
            },
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'floating-label-template.html'
        }}
 )
```

Directive's template:

```
<div class="field">
      <label ng-show="value" class="show-hide">{{label}}</label>
      <div ng-transclude></div>
 </div>
```

I'm trying to use it in the following way:

```
<input floating-label label="Floating" value="floatingDirective"  type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="floatingDirective"/>
```

Plunker with my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/MC8G4H3B9zEleaBZ7ijJ?p=preview

**P.S. I'm using AngularJS 1.4.9**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/h5bAk8v6pGDT0atWXwrs?p=preview).

Read this : [**What is ng-transclude**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24725399/what-is-ng-transclude)

> Directive that marks the insertion point for the transcluded DOM of the nearest parent directive that uses transclusion.

Why your code not working: you have nothing to be **'*transclude*'**.

A general markup of use directive with `ng-transclude` may like this:

```
<directive-with-ng-transclude>
  <node-to-transclude></node-to-transclude>
</directive-with-ng-transclude>
```

After compiled, `<node-to-transclude></node-to-transclude>` will be appended to the template of your directive where you put `ng-transclude`.

**Notice** : [ng-model inside ng-transclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701829/ng-model-inside-ng-transclude) , that's why I use a dotted ng-model `floatingDirective`.